# How to Continue Training from the last acquired best weights?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tf.keras, yolov4

[Keras implementation of YOLOv4](https://github.com/taipingeric/yolo-v4-tf.keras)

Is it possible in this Keras implementation of YOLOv4 to somehow continue training from the last saved best weights? Something like the following:

```
model_checkpoint_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath=checkpoint_filepath,
    monitor='val_binary_accuracy',
    mode='max',
    save_best_only=True)

model.load_weights(checkpoint_filepath)
```

Comment: please clarify What do you mean by continuing training? Do you want to use existing weights to do transfer learning and start from those weights instead of random initialization?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want to use weights acquired in the last epoch completed with reduced validation loss. How would you do that in this implementation?

Comment: @let me know if my answer address your question, whatever checkpoint you have just pass it the the function in the answer and it will start initialize model with those weights if the model structures is compatible

Comment: the function in your question is [callback](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/model_checkpoint/) and the `filepath` in it is a place that the model will use to save checkpoints not to load. but if you want to load saved weights; just use my answer and pass the `checkpoint_filepath` to `weight_path` of that function then model will sort using those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [these lines](https://github.com/taipingeric/yolo-v4-tf.keras/blob/73dfe97c00a03ebb7fab00a5a0549b958172482a/models.py#L75) the repository automatically handles the weights on your path; So to load a pre-trained weights (either `.h5` checkpoint or `.weights` to do transfer learning, and follow training notebooks for the rest;

```
model = Yolov4(weight_path='mytraining.weights', 
               class_name_path=class_name_path)
```

**Update:** (from the comments of OP)

Pre-trained weights can be loaded for transfer learning by passing the path to ".h5" checkpoint file to  `weight_path` argumentwith the following amendment in `models.py`: replace [line 75](https://github.com/taipingeric/yolo-v4-tf.keras/blob/73dfe97c00a03ebb7fab00a5a0549b958172482a/models.py#L75):

```py
if load_pretrained and self.weight_path and self.weight_path.endswith('.weights'):
```

with:

```py
if load_pretrained and self.weight_path and (self.weight_path.endswith('.weights') or self.weight_path.endswith('.h5')):
```

This issue is addressed in this [PR](https://github.com/taipingeric/yolo-v4-tf.keras/pull/10).

Comment: I have files with names such as "epoch_01-val_loss-1707.6603.hdf5" saved in the checkpoint folder. Passing paths of these files to "weight_path" doesn't help. Retraining initializes random weights.

Comment: In fact, how do I save "mytraining.weights" with each epoch in this implementation?

Comment: @SamamaFahim as the [code implemented](https://github.com/taipingeric/yolo-v4-tf.keras/blob/73dfe97c00a03ebb7fab00a5a0549b958172482a/models.py#L80) you can directly pass your h5 to `load_weights` function also documentation on the [function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#load_weights) suggest the same thing. So, my guess is there is a problem with how you pass the checkpoint. be aware that you should pass a file with name `.h5` since the code is written in that. So, just rename your `.hdf5`to`.h5` and pass it.

Comment: I renamed the .hdf5 to .h5. Still starts from a very big loss.

Comment: @SamamaFahim Is it the same when you use? `yolov4.weights`? if yes, it is definitely your pathing issue; if you are passing with  `yolov4.weights` the file should be at the folder you run the code. you can check your path with `!pwd` if you are using jupyers and with `!ls` you should see the file

Comment: I'm passing the absolute g-drive path: "/content/drive/MyDrive/Paper/checkpoints/epoch_04-val_loss-24.4041.h5"

Comment: @SamamaFahim I suggest not to use the drive in that way, meaning directly upload instead to collab instead of reading from a mounted drive and test again. I had issues with my data when mounting from gdrive.

Comment: Should I save the checkpoint files to cwd?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243501/discussion-between-sadra-naddaf-and-samama-fahim).

Comment: Pre-trained weights can be loaded for transfer learning by passing the path to ".h5" checkpoint file to `weight_path` with the following amendment in `models.py`: replace line 75 `if load_pretrained and self.weight_path and self.weight_path.endswith('.weights'):` with `if load_pretrained and self.weight_path and (self.weight_path.endswith('.weights') or self.weight_path.endswith('.h5')):`